# Vim: How to scrollbind the cursor line too?

Tags: vim

Two windows in a split windows view of Vim can be bound to each other for **scrolling** by setting `:set scrollbind` for both of them. After this is done, if I scroll down the cursor in one windows, the other windows scrolls down along with it.

But, the cursors in the two windows are not bound to each other. I have used `:set cursorline` to highlight the current line on which the cursor is present. How do I make the highlighted **cursorline** to scroll simultaneously in the other window too?

Comment: I can't tell if you want to bind the relative offsets of multiple windows with `scrollbind` or to set the absolute offset of the cursor with `cursorbind`

Comment: Puk: Two split windows are already bound. Now, I want the cursors to also move down the same lines in the windows. So, if I move cursor from window-line 10 to 11 in window 1, I want the same to happen in window 2.

Comment: essentially what you want is the two windows, regardless of whether they are displaying the same file, two always point to the same line? Can you not achieve that by going to the top of both files (`gg`) before issuing `set scrollbind`?

Answer (score 24):

I don't use this myself, and I may be missing the point, but

```
:set cursorbind
```

seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: And still, I learned something new about vim today. What a rich application it is!

Comment: Prince Goulash: Thanks, the cursorbind command seems to go halfway there. The cursor is not updated while I scroll the windows. But, when I switch to the next window, the cursor is synced.

Comment: @Ashwin I have the same problem here. Have you found a solution to that?

Comment: @Yang: No, I haven't got :-(

Comment: You have to `:set cursorbind` in all tabs/splits you want bound! It's working for me. Also, it won't follow when you're scrolling but after you tap a `h,j,k,l` after scrolling then it will sync with linenumber/column

Comment: The cursor updates. `:setlocal cursorline` and you will see. `:set scrollbind` and `:set cursorbind` is what I looked for, with `cursorline`. Neovim behaves as you would expect, I think, with the cursors aligned, but Vim behaves a little strange unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like the cursor only binds to both windows when both cursors are no more than one character away from the end of the line.

Answer (score 12):

I just encountered the same situation (with only two windows to compare), and what I did was:

```
:set cursorbind
:set scrollbind
:set cursorline
```

and then

```
:map <Down> j<C-w><C-w><C-w><C-w>
:map <Up> k<C-w><C-w><C-w><C-w>
```

This causes every press on the up or down arrows to switch back and forth between the windows once, which updates the cursor position on the other window (You can `:redraw!<CR>` instead of the ugly window switching but that looks bad when moving too fast). Of course, there are many ways to move between lines without the arrows, so this is far from perfect.

However, since this is not a main mode of work for me, useful primarily for comparing files on which `diff` is too complicated to look at for whatever reason, I find this setting to be practically good enough.

Comment: One can use ':syncbind' instead of switching between windows. i.e. :map j j:syncbind<cr>

Answer (score 6):

I came up with this solution when I wanted to do a "cross-window column tracking" in a `vimdiff` session (in additional to "cross-window row tracking"). Probably this would solve your problem as well.

First enable `cursorcolumn`, `cursorbind`, `cursorline` and `scrollbind` on each window.

```
:windo set cursorcolumn | set cursorbind | set cursorline | set scrollbind
```

Then `map` the `hjkl` motion keys to update the cursor position for each movement.

```
:nmap h h:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
:nnoremap j j:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>j:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
:nmap k k:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
:nmap l l:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this page in the vim documentation thought you might find it helpful: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-binding

Sometimes I find that straight from the horses mouth is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I made a tiny change to [`cychoi`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458325/278405). Remap `h,j,k,l` in the diff mode and remove a 'j' hit in `cychoi`'s original mapping:

```
if &diff
  au VimEnter * windo set cursorcolumn | set cursorbind | set cursorline | set scrollbind
  nmap h h:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
  nmap j j:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
  nmap k k:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
  nmap l l:let curwin=winnr()<CR>:keepjumps windo redraw<CR>:execute curwin . "wincmd w"<CR>
endif
```

I think this setting is good for CSV line-by-line diff.