# How to highlight current lines in two buffers while scrolling simultaneously in vim?

Tags: vim

[set scrollbind](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Scrolling_synchronously) works great for synchronising a couple of scrolling buffers.

[set cursorline](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line) works great for highlighting the current line in a buffer.

**QUESTION**

*Is there a way to highlight the same line in two buffers?*

I am editing on a big screen two buffers, one in language A, and the other in language B (translation).  When editing in language A, I would like the corresponding line in B highlighted, and vice versa.  These two commands almost do what I want - the scrolling works, but the highlighting only occurs in the active buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the cursorbind option, [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227964/vim-how-to-scrollbind-the-cursor-line-too).

The cursor only updates when you move between windows, but you can workaround with some mappings, as explained on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20174861/717124).